# is it possible to create an array of type declarations in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, inheritance

I was wondering if there was a way to create an array that contains type declarations to more easily and more flexibly declare a larger number of variables of different types.

For instance, what I'm trying to do is have an array of a parent class and I want to declare a dynamic pointer array of the parent class' children.

Here is an example class declaration:

```cpp
class parent {
   private:
      int x;
}

class child1 : public parent {
   private:
      int y;
}

class child2 : public parent {
    private:
      int z;
}
```

Here is what I'm doing manually:

```cpp
parent *array[100];
int count = 0;
int child1_num = 25, child2_num = 75;
for (int i = 0; i < child1_num; i++) {
   parent[count++] = new child1;
} 
for (int i = 0; i < child2_num; i++) {
   parent[count++] = new child2;
}
```

I am hoping I can get it in a form similar to:

```cpp
parent *array[100];
child_type type[2] = {child1, child2};
int child_num[2] = {25, 75};
int count  = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < child_num[i]; j++) {
       array[count++] = new type[i];
   }
}
```

If there is a better way of going about this? I couldn't come up with anything else.

Comment: std::tuple is better option with C++11, if you dont have that you can try boost::mpl
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, via type lists (first popularised in the book Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu). See: [Type list with boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208180/type-list-with-boost)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but you don't need typelists. There are other ways to improve your code. Use basic c++11 features first, say, `std::vector` instead of an array and `std::unique_ptr` instead of naked pointers.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<parent>> v;
    int child1_num = 25, child2_num = 75;
    for (int i = 0; i < child1_num; i++) {
        v.emplace_back(new child1);
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < child2_num; i++) {
        v.emplace_back(new child2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then you can go further and create a function like

```
template<typename T, typename Vector>
void fill(Vector& v, size_t count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        v.emplace_back(new T);
    }
}
```

and simplify your main code

```
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<parent>> v;
    int child1_num = 25, child2_num = 75;
    fill<child1>(v, child1_num);
    fill<child2>(v, child2_num);
```

and stop here. It is enough. You don't need typelists. And don't forget about virtual destructor in `parent`.